# Linux bash: run script as a non-root user by a non-root user using PHP

Tags: permissions, bash, php-fpm

I have a PHP script owned by "tom" (runs using PHP-FPM). "tom" wants to run the script /srv/helloworld.sh as another user called "jerry". "tom" has the access to run scripts on the server (so he can use ex. system()).

The long and the short, "tom" wants to know how to do this.
"tom" readed some article about this:

```
sudo su -c /srv/helloworld.sh jerry
```

But the main problem is that, the script asks for a password and you know, (if I am not mistaken) there is no way to enter password in a web interface.

I am really curious about this topic and I would be pleased if you could help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man sudoers` has all the information you need.

You need the command `sudo -u jerry /srv/helloworld.sh` and have to change `/etc/sudoers` so that tom is allowed to execute this without having to enter a passwort. `NOPASSWD` is your key word.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure sudo to allow tom to run that script as jerry without a password. Read up on sudoers - I would start with "man sudoers".